# /usr/bin/gcc-4.2: No such file or directory. error. symlink fix doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, osx-mountain-lion

I'm trying to upgrade my rails 3.2.3 app. I've updated the gemfile to `gem 'rails', '3.2.11'` and ran `bundle update rails` but got the following error:

```
    Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /Users/Arel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-head/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
creating Makefile

make
compiling generator.c
make: /usr/bin/gcc-4.2: No such file or directory
make: *** [generator.o] Error 1


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/Arel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head/gems/json-1.7.6 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/Arel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head/gems/json-1.7.6/ext/json/ext/generator/gem_make.out
An error occured while installing json (1.7.6), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install json -v '1.7.6'` succeeds before bundling.
```

So I tried the solution that I found everywhere, to create a symlink using the command:

`sudo ln -s /usr/bin/gcc /usr/bin/gcc-4.2`

but that just returns the error:

`ln: /usr/bin/gcc-4.2: File exists`

I don't know a lot about using the terminal to navigate around OSX, so I'm kind of struggling here. Any ideas?

Comment: What does "ls -la /usr/bin/gcc-4.2" say?  It could be a broken symlink currently.

Comment: @Bribles you were right! I found the file, deleted it, and re ran the symlink command and it worked! If you put your comment as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`/usr/bin/gcc-4.2` could already be a symlink, but a broken one that points to a nonexistent file.

Comment: How to fix this broken symbolic link? I removed the gcc file and then wrote - sudo ln -s /usr/bin/gcc-6  /usr/bin/gcc